# Como implementar una validacion Regex en las celdas de QTableWidget PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

He estado investigando sobre como validar las celdas de una `QTableWidget` para que solo acepte numeros flotantes. Encontre que usando un `QItemDelegate` podemos implementar esta validacion pero solo encontre ejemplos en C++ por lo que se me hizo deficil tratar de implementarlo en Python y PyQt5.

Este es el codigo que genere, para tratar de solo permitir numeros flotentes pero no funciona.
Anexo el codigo.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel,QItemDelegate,QTableWidgetItem,QLineEdit,QTableWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator,QRegExpValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp

class Delegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self):
        line = QLineEdit(self)
        validador = QRegExp("[0-9.0-9]*")
        ok = QRegExpValidator(validador,self)
        line.setValidator(ok)
        return line

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.w = QLineEdit(self)
        self.tabla = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tabla.setRowCount(1)
        self.tabla.setColumnCount(1)
        self.tabla.setItemDelegate(Delegate())
        self.tabla.setCellWidget(0,0,self.w)
        self.tabla.show()
        self.tabla.resize(400,300)


app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.resize(800,600)
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intentalo:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QLabel,QItemDelegate, \
    QTableWidgetItem,QLineEdit,QTableWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator,QRegExpValidator, QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp, Qt

       
class Delegate(QItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):     # self, parent, option, index    
       
        line = QLineEdit(parent)                       #  parent
        
        # try it:
        validador = QRegExp("[0-9.0-9]*")
        ok = QRegExpValidator(validador, parent)
        line.setValidator(ok)
        
        # or try it:                                      # <<<-----<
        #line.setInputMask("0.0;")                        # <<<-----<
        
        return line 
        
        
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
#        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        
        self.tabla = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tabla.setRowCount(4)
        self.tabla.setColumnCount(3)
        
        self.tabla.setItemDelegate(Delegate())
        
#        self.tabla.setCellWidget(0, 0, self.lineEdit)
#        self.tabla.show()
#        self.tabla.resize(400,300)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabla)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = Main()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: funciono muchas gracias podrias ayudarme diciendome como usar las opciones index y option de la clase Delegate

Comment: @Revsky01 intenta leer https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemdelegate.html#createEditor